# Typo3 9.x ajax call

Tags: ajax, routes, typo3

Configuration about a single route for ajax call: **getamministrazioni.json**

I tried to change configuration site as follow:

```
...


    routeEnhancers:
      News:
        type: Extbase
        extension: News
        plugin: Pi1
        routes:
          -
            routePath: '/{news-title}'
            _controller: 'News::detail'
            _arguments:
              news-title: news
        aspects:
          news-title:
            type: PersistedAliasMapper
            tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
            routeFieldName: path_segment
      PageTypeSuffix:
        type: PageType
        default: .html
        map:
          .html: 0
          getamministrazioni.json: 1035343

    errorHandling: {  }
    routes: {  }
...
```

And in setup.typoscript i have:

```
GetAmministrazioni = PAGE
GetAmministrazioni {
typeNum = 1035343
config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    debug = 0
    no_cache = 1
    additionalHeaders {
      10 {
        header = Content-Type: application/json
        replace = 1
      }
    }
}
 10 < tt_content.list.20.my_controller_getamministrazioni

}
```

It works but for all pages.

1. /home/getamministrazioni.json
2. /page1/getamministrazioni.json

etc.. etc..

I want a single route from root '/getamministrazioni.json

how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to limit the routing to specific page ids:

```
limitToPages: 1
```

But this will limit your whole mapping configuration to page id 1, also the .html suffix (which you don't want to, I guess).

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to create multiple Route Enhancers with the same name, like in the following, **non-working example**:

```
PageTypeSuffix:
  type: PageType
  map:
    .html: 0
PageTypeSuffix:
  type: PageType
  limitToPages: 1
  map:
    sitemap.xml: 1533906435
```

### Two possible workarounds:

1. **Create your own RouteEnhancer**, which just extends TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Enhancer\PageTypeDecorator to allow a different name (see [custom enhancers](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html#enhancers))
2. **Redirect** your json page type to an error page, if page id is not 0 (no routing neccessary, as TypoScript avoids delivering of this page type)

   `[getTSFE().id != 1]
     seo_sitemap.config {
       additionalHeaders.10 {
         header = Location: /error.html
       }
     }
   [END]`

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. I create a plugin and i use controller to print json and i 'return' false. In template setup strip all html and i change header content type. So in every page i insert a a plugin as content that print the json